# Is there a syslog daemon that implements RFC 5848 "Signed Syslog Messages"?

Tags: security, syslog

I was looking at the Syslog standards and found [RFC 5848 "Signed Syslog Messages"](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5848). I then tried to find out which `syslog` daemons supported this standard. But to my surprise `syslog-ng` and `rsyslog` both don't support it.

I only found an old presentation from 2002 for FreeBSD, but to my knowledge FreeBSD doesn't support [this](http://2002.eurobsdcon.org/papers/mietus_presentation.pdf).

So my questions:

- which Syslog implementation(s) do support RFC 5848?
- It would also be nice to know why it is not implemented?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although there is no official support in syslog-ng, giova23 needed the same feature and wrote a plugin called syslog-sign. It's on github, please follow the [link](https://github.com/giova23/syslog-sign). Installation instructions are provided.